# Bitmap to byte[]

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a problem with saving an image (or a bitmapImage or a PhotoResult) to a byte[] and then converting it back to an image.

I found a lot of posts on the internet about it but they dont work. In this code I got an `Unspecifed error` when I do this: `SetSource ( bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);)` and dont know how to do that.

I also want to make a list of Devices (each with a name, id, status and an image which I will represent as a `byte[]`) and save it to IsolatedStorage, and then read it and list them (with an image of course.)

Here is some code I have so far:

```
public void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {


        imageBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
        e.ChosenPhoto.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

       BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
        try
        {
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception ea)
        {
            //
        }
            image1.Source = bitmapImage;

    }
```

Comment: This is really two separate questions and should be separated as such.

Comment: the question is: hot to convert imageor bitmap to byte[]

Comment: Then remove the "I also want to make a list of Devices...." part as it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Microsoft.Phone.PictureDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.phone.picturedecoder%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) class? It has a [DecodeJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.picturedecoder.decodejpeg%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) function that returns an instance of a WritableBitmap object.

Another solution is to use the [WritableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) extension library that makes digital image processing much easier and has a very good performance. The function you need is called FromByteArray.

In both cases you'll have to use a WriteableBitmap, because BitmapImage is protected from modification. Since both BitmapImage and WriteableBitmap are subclasses of BitmapSource, you can easily display them in the image control.

Hope it helps!